# How do I get the User's operating system?

Tags: c, operating-system, systems-programming

I am writing a C program, part of which requires me to get the User's operating system. For example, to get the home directory I can do the following:

```
const char *homedir;
homedir = getpwuid(getuid())->pw_dir;
printf("Home dir: %s\n",homedir);
```

I can not locate anything related to the OS in `pwd.h` is there a different file I should be looking at ?

Comment: "How do I get the User's operating system in UNIX?" – um, `return "Unix";`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Sorry, that was a bad question, I meant, get the user's operating system in general through a C program. My apologies.

Comment: I get that it's not pretty, but you can just check for the existence of some characteristic filesystem paths. `/usr` will usually mean a UNIX of some kind, `/Applications`, `/Library`, and `/Users` all indicates OSX, `C:/`  anything or `System32` indicates Windows, and so on. From there you can look at things like `uname` or some Win32 API call to get more specific version information.

Comment: The C language does not define a method of querying the OS name, or indeed stipulate that there is an OS. Why would your program need to know that?

Comment: @Linuxios A single executable program normally cannot contain both uname and a WinAPI call, and call either depending on some run-time condition.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion as to what you want.  The 2 answers so far return information *about* the OS, whereas your question seems to imply you want access to the directory of the OS.  If you tell us what you want to *do* (rather than what think you *want*) we may better be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times (it's not guaranteed), a C compiler defines macros that identify the current operating system (the macro-family, at the very least).

Eg. to identify Windows, Linux and Mac you could do:

```
#import <stdio.h>

typedef enum {

  UNKNOWN,
  WINDOWS,
  LINUX,
  OSX

} OS;

OS current_os();

int main() {

  printf("%d",current_os());
  return 0;

}

OS current_os() {
  #ifdef _WIN32
    return WINDOWS;
  #elif (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
    return OSX;
  #elif defined(__gnu_linux__)
    return LINUX;
  #else
    return UNKNOWN;
  #endif 
}
```

On my Mac this prints 3, like it's supposed to do.

You can find a comprehensive list of those macros [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/).

Answer (score 2):

On SVr4 and POSIX.1-2001 and later compliant UNIXes, use `uname()` -- for more info, `man 2 uname` to info about which UNIX, kernel version, and hardware identifier you are on.

Not sure for non-UNIX.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you'll use Win API functions to get exact version (such as `GetVersionEx` API call).

On Linux - you can use `uname(struct utsname *buf)` call (`man 2 uname`).

Other platforms may provide different APIs.

If you want to be portable across operating systems, you should provide a layer of abstraction that hides OS-specific calls and compile-in proper platform-specific implementation that shares a common interface.

Abstractions - this is The Way in cross-platform programming.

Alternatively, you may use pre-processor, which provides some basic platform information at compile-time. Preprocessor is used quite often to select platform-specific code to compile.